# Powershell Syntax Error (python 2.7)

Tags: python, powershell, syntax-error

Python 2.7

When I try and execute a python script, I get an invalid syntax error.

```
powershell.exe 'c:\pythonscripts\ex1.py'
File "<stdin>", line 1
powershell.exe 'c:\pythonscripts\ex1.py'
                                       ^
```

I know it works because I just executed a file with this command.
the code for the .py is

```
print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'Yay! Printing.'
print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
print 'I "said" do not touch this.
```

Python 2.7

Comment: You're missing a `'` after the last print statement, or was this a mistake in formatting your question

Comment: Thank you :) It was the mistake... Derp me lol. Now I just need to figure out how to pause.... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the comments, you're mistake is that you forgot an apostrophe in your last print statement.

```
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

Have fun learning python. LPTHW is a great way to learn it :).

Comment: @user2127874 if you found the answer helpful, could you please accept the answer (click the tick) to show others it was the most helpful answer? Thanks :)